# How can I set the number of iterations to run in a recursive function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, recursion

How can I set the number of iterations to run in a recursive function in Matlab?
I have the following function

```
function t=m(x1,x2)
if x1<0.5
    if x2<0.5
        t=(0+m(2*x2, 2*x1))/4;
    else
        t=(1+m(2*x1, 2*x2-1))/4;
    end
else
    if x2>=0.5
       t=(2+m(2*x1-1, 2*x2-1))/4;
    else
       t=(3+m(1-2*x2, 2-2*x1))/4;
    end
end

end
```

I want it to perform `10^3` iterations.

I tried with

```
function t=m(x1,x2,iter)
while iter<=10^3
      if x1<0.5
         if x2<0.5
            t=(0+m(2*x2, 2*x1, iter+1))/4;
         else
            t=(1+m(2*x1, 2*x2-1, iter+1))/4;
         end
      else
        if x2>=0.5
           t=(2+m(2*x1-1, 2*x2-1, iter+1))/4;
        else
           t=(3+m(1-2*x2, 2-2*x1, iter+1))/4;
        end
      end
end
end
```

and in the main

```
    x1=0.3;
    x2=0.4;
    iter=0;
    t=m(x1,x2,iter);
```

but it gives me several errors. Any help?

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no sense. This is not just some iterative convergence process where you can choose how many iterations you want to run. When you define a recursion, there should be some edge case which computes the result without another recursive call, thus stopping it from going deeper. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks. Can't the edge case be "when you hit the number of iterations=10^3 stop and give me what you have"?

Comment: Yes, that can be your edge case, but it will be like `if(iter>=1e3), t=_some_value_; return; end;`. You don't need a `while` loop in addition to recursion, and it's not clear what you mean by "what you have" - it has to be some combination of `x1` and `x2`,

Comment: Thanks. "m" is the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't put that loop inside your function. Repeating is the role of recursion. So change your function to:

```
function t=m(x1,x2,iter)
t = 0;
if iter > 0
      if x1<0.5
         if x2<0.5
            t=(0+m(2*x2, 2*x1, iter-1))/4;
         else
            t=(1+m(2*x1, 2*x2-1, iter-1))/4;
         end
      else
        if x2>=0.5
           t=(2+m(2*x1-1, 2*x2-1, iter-1))/4;
        else
           t=(3+m(1-2*x2, 2-2*x1, iter-1))/4;
        end
      end     
end
end
```

(supposing you want it to return 0 after the last iteration)

Now you can call your function like this:

```
m(0.3, 0.4, 10^3)
```

But before that, call:

```
set(0,'RecursionLimit',10^3+2)
```

For these inputs, it converges to 0.1808 after only 8 iterations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I wanted. Could I ask you if possible whether including "return" would be an alternative and how?